# Should we not declare a method static if it depends on instance creation?

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I read this about when we should use static functions, but I didn't understand it. Can someone please explain this with an example?

> You should use static methods whenever,
>
> The code in the method is not dependent on instance creation and is not using any instance variable.

Source : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/When-to-use-static-methods-in-Java

Comment: Anyone can make any claim, right or wrong. It would be useful to add to your question where your claim is coming from. Whether it's a book, or an article/post on the web, etc. It is unclear what the claim really means with "is not dependent on instance creation" and knowing where the claim comes from also helps to add such context.

Comment: Erwin, what "not dependent on instance creation" means is that this is a method which should be able to do its work, even when an instance of the class has not been created.  The advice that Harshit has quoted is more tautological than helpful, if you ask me.

Comment: It seems reasonable to have quoted that advice in his question, given that it is (a) obviously true, and (b) necessary to understand what he is asking. If he took it out, then he would need to paraphrase it to explain what his question is, and he needs to understand it to effectively paraphrase it.

Comment: I've edited the description and added the source.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are different from non-static methods in that they are not associated with any particular object, and therefore do not allow you to reference `this` inside them. That includes implicit references to `this`. Methods are normally non-static because most of them define behaviours of objects, and that behaviour requires an instance of the class to have any meaning. For example, a List class would have a non-static method that appends something to the list. That method needs an actual instance of a list to make sense - if you just said "append 5 to the list" then the response would be "which list?". The syntax for that ends up looking like `myList.push(5);`, where you specify what list you want to append to by putting a reference to the object before the dot. If, however, you had an operation that didn't need an instance of the class, then it would be silly to need to construct one to call the function. For example, the square root function doesn't depend on some math object that needs to be constructed, it only operates on a single number. So, to avoid making you do something like `new Math().sqrt(5);`, they make a static method, which you can call like `Math.sqrt(5);`.